# Less font family syntax

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

In a bootstrap's Less file, I've noticed the following declarations:

```
@font-family-sans-serif:  "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
@font-family-serif:       Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
@font-family-monospace:   Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
```

How to read this syntax? What does the order of the values there mean and why are some of them in apostrophes?

Comment: Those are variable declarations.  You're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Answer (score 0):

Those are bootstrap variables and bootstrap uses `@font-family-sans-serif` as the `@font-family-base`. The font family will be executed in this order.

1. Roboto
2. Helvetica Neue
3. Helvetica
4. Arial
5. sans-serif

If the system can't find the 1st font, It will look for the 2nd font, If the system can't find it neither, it will look for the 3rd font and so on.

I think the apostrophes are used if it is not in the default system(web safe fonts) and/or if it is more than 1 word.

Please correct me if there's something wrong with my answer.